# Right click a csv file to read in RStudio?

Tags: csv, right-click, r, rstudio

I would like the ability to right click on a .csv file and read it in [RStudio](http://www.rstudio.com/) (an IDE for the statistical language [R](http://www.r-project.org/)). When I say "read it in RStudio" I mean open up RStudio with the line `dat<-read.csv(file location + file name)` already there.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: What happens when you right-click, select open-with, and select RStudio?

Comment: @fixer1234 It just dumps the entire csv file into a new R script.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've ever seen this is not possible for one simple reason. What object is R to store the data in when invoked?

The beauty of R is its flexibility in object names when storing data. A storage protocol would be required and then it would need to check to make sure the item isn't overwriting a previously stored item. Long and short of it, it'd be easier to code in the `read.csv()` than it would be to add this functionality in the program itself.